# Placing border-spacing for all rows expect the first, and last, using nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table, border-spacing

I'm trying to place border-spacing for all rows except the first, and last row, by using nth-child, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
table {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 98%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}
td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
border-spacing : 0px 0px; 
}
tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
border-spacing : 0px 0px; 
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) {
border-spacing : 0px 0px; 
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) {
border-spacing : 0px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td> row1 col1 </td><td> row1 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row2 col1 </td><td> row2 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row3 col1 </td><td> row3 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row4 col1 </td><td> row4 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row5 col1 </td><td> row5 col2 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `border-spacing` is a property of the `table`, not of the `row` or `cell`. So, it is not working for cell

Comment: @ketan So we can't do it using nth-child?

Comment: No, we can't give border-spacing to `tr` or `td`.

Answer (score 2):

check code below and You can apply `border-spacing` effect to table not for `td or tr`, you can only use padding for `td` directly and then use `:first-child and :last-child` to remove padding for first and last `td or tr`.

```css
table {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 98%;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 10px 50px;
}

td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 50px 10px;
}

tr:first-child td,tr:last-child td {
  padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td> row1 col1 </td><td> row1 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row2 col1 </td><td> row2 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row3 col1 </td><td> row3 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row4 col1 </td><td> row4 col2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> row5 col1 </td><td> row5 col2 </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then `border-spacing` isn't what you're after, but the effect should be achievable with padding. Something like the following can give you the kind of variable spacing you seem to be after:

```
td {
  padding: 50px 10px;
}
tr:first-child td,
tr:last-child td {
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Since you say that you want to target the first and last row, `:first-child` and `:last-child` are better suited than to the task than `:nth-child`, which is better for more complex selections like patterns (e.g., every 3rd child, etc.).

I suspect the borders were added for clarity, but if you need them, you can do something like wrap a `div` around =the content of each `td` that has padding and give a 1px border to `td div` (which selects any `div` within a `td`).

But if the padding gets you where you want to be in terms of spacing, the rest can be hacked away easily enough.